# Am I doing something wrong with this xmlhttp GET Request?

Tags: html, excel, xml, vba, xmlhttprequest

Currently, this is what I have. Everything works, but it seems that it debugs at the xmlhttp.send (urlbody) part. It gives me a debug error and I can't seem to find exactly the issue within my code. If any of you can figure out exactly where it is, that would be very appreciated. Is there a place in which I have to put it, that it isn't currently in?

```
Sub productIDGrab()
Dim xmlhttp As Object
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
Dim urlBody As String

Token = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A2").Value
Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
Cells.Range("$A$2").Select
i = 2
Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))

   i = i + 1

Biscuit = ActiveCell.Value

URL1 = "https://api.channeladvior.com/v1/Products?access_token=" & Token & "&$filter=Sku eq '" & Biscuit & "' &$select=ID"
xmlhttp.Open "POST", URL1, False

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/JSON"
xmlhttp.send (urlBody)

productid = xmlhttp.responseText
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = productid
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
newHour = Hour(Now())
newMinute = Minute(Now())
newSecond = Second(Now()) + 3
waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
Application.Wait waitTime
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: `https://api.channeladvior.com` are you sure that's the URL you want ?  Seems like you might have a typo.

Comment: Looks like it should be https://api.channeladvisor.com